# TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, promise, sails.js, bluebird, sails-orientdb

I have the following code executing inside a controller in Sailsjs. The underlying adapter is sails-orientdb. I get the following error back

TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

Why is this error occurring?

```
        User.query("select id from User where username='" + req.param("userid") + "'").then(function(userData){
        console.log(userData);
        return userData;
    }).fail(function (err) {
        console.log("Handled");
    });
```

Comment: Try `User.queryAsync`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what @jaumard said.

### Background

Usually it's recommend to use the [standard waterline query methods](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#query-methods) such as `find()`, `update()`, `create()`, `destroy()`, etc. These methods support callbacks and promises and these methods will work the same way against any waterline adapter (OrientDB, MySQL, MongoDB, etc).

Sometimes you may want to do something more complex which is not supported by the standard waterline methods and for that sails-orientdb extends the waterline definition with `query()`, among [other methods](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb#methods).

### sails-orientdb `.query()`

sails-orientdb query uses callback so you can use it like this:

```
  // Assume a model named "Friend"
  Friend.query("SELECT FROM friendTable WHERE name='friend query'", function(err, retrievedUsers){
    console.log(retrievedUsers);
  });
```

**UPDATE:** since v0.10.53 the below is also supported:

```
Friend.query("SELECT FROM friendTable WHERE name='friend query'")
.then(function(retrievedUsers){
  console.log(retrievedUsers);
});
```

If you really want to use the promise mechanism you have 2 options:

#### promisify `query()`

By using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function) promise's promisify. Example:

```
var queryPromise = Promise.promisify(User.query);
queryPromise('select...').then(function(){/*...*/})
```

#### Use `getDB()`

Another option is to use sails-orientdb custom method [`getDB`](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb#getdb-). This method returns an [Oriento](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) `db` instance which can be used for promisified queries. Example:

```
User.getDB().query('select from OUser where name=:name', {
  params: {
    name: 'Radu'
  },
  limit: 1
}).then(function (results){
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: I was executing a sequence of queries and I have to return an a JSON object that gets rendered on the front-end. One of those queries was a custom query using the graph methods of orient. The above provides the solution.

Comment: @TommyK, since v0.10.53 `.query` also supports promises. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think promise works with .query method (maybe I'm wrong). 
You can use this instead :

```
User.findOne()
.where({ username: req.param("userid") })
.then(function(user){
    return user;
}).then(function(user){
    //Do what you want 
}).catch(function(err){
    // An error occurred
});
```

With sails and waterline it's not recommended to use .query when you not really need to.

See this tutorial it may help : http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial/chaining

Comment: In some cases I need to use .query. How do I use promises with that?

Comment: I just think you can't use promise with .query but don't know enough promise, I never use .query and promise sorry.